# unicode header included in first line of file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm printing the first line from a file:

```
with open(path,"r",encoding='utf8') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        print(bytes(l.rstrip(), encoding='utf8'))
```

which I expect to output b'1' but instead I'm getting:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf1'
```

what's the issue here?

I'm on windows and I saved my file using notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTF-8 representation of the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. A text editor or web browser interpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.

---

BOM in `UTF-8` is not needed. You can configure Notepad++.

Comment: Unfortunately Windows will never just assume that a file is in UTF-8 - the choices are use a BOM or roll the dice.

Comment: The fact that the Unicode standard explicitly says you should not use the BOM in UTF-8 for any purpose, and yet Windows uses it all over the place as a way to say "this file is actually in UTF-8 even if that's not the default encoding", is exactly why utf-8-sig has to exist…

Answer (score 6):

To correctly parse the BOM, use [utf-8-sig](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs#module-encodings.utf_8_sig):

```
with open(path,"r",encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about this one. Use it only for reading, never writing unless there's no alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing the [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) that Notepad++ put at the beginning of the file to mark it as UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I expected readlines() to strip away this as it has no connection with the notion of a line imo

Comment: @Baz, readlines() doesn't try to interpret the characters in a line other than the line ending itself.

Comment: @Baz: It's not readlines that should strip it, it's the file decoder. But you've explicitly asked for the decode that doesn't strip the BOM ('utf-8'), not the one that does ('utf-8-sig'). The reason there are two different codecs is that often you need to MS-ify or de-MS-ify some UTF-8, while other times you don't care and want them to look the same either way.